# How to make curl reconnect after 60"?

Tags: bash, curl

Sometimes, `curl` freezes:

```
$ curl -O 'http://www.site.com/index.html'

  www.site.com/index.html --> index.html
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:17 --:--:--     0^C
```

After waiting for `137"`, I hit <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, and re-download.

---

```
$ curl -O 'http://www.site.com/index.html'

  www.site.com/index.html --> index.html
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 49045    0 49045    0     0   4598      0 --:--:--  0:00:10 --:--:--  6078
```

It just takes `10"` to download.

---

It sounds like, `curl` is waiting for response for ever.
How to make `curl` reconnect automatically after `60"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

retry 3 times, each time 60" at most:

```
curl -O --retry 3 -m 60 'http://www.site.com/index.html'
```